# postgis projection pixel shp2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, postgis, projection, shapefile, map-projections

I have created a database and enabled it spatially with postgis.
I would like to store data from a shapefile into it. If I specify a projection, it works well.

But, we would like to store in pixel projection, meaning no projection. If I do not give any projection information or give null value to s paramater, it does not work. How can I store the data from the shapefile to table in pixel projection?

shp2pgsql -d -s 4326 -I test.shp public.test | psql -h <<>> -d <<>>

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific about how it does not work without the -s parameter? I have imported without a SRID many times, though I don't generally think it is a good idea, but that is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that works with shp2pgsql, but the srid -1 means an unknown reference system (so no projection) in postgis.